# Coordinate Geometry: Are there enough information to find out the coordinates?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

> > Question: Given the circle $x^2+y^2=25$ is inscribed in triangle $\triangle ABC$, where vertex $B$ lies on the first quadrant. Slope of $AB$ is $\sqrt 3$ and has a positive y-coordinate, and $|AB|=|AC|$. Find the equations for $AC$ and $BC$

I found out the equation for the straight line passing through $AB$: Let the line be $y=\sqrt 3 x+c$. Then

$3x^2+2\sqrt 3 cx+c^2+x^2=25$

$\Delta =0$ (discriminant)

$(2\sqrt 3 c)^2 - 4(4)(c^2-25)=0$

$c=10$

---

However, I don't see any simple way to find out the equations of line for $AC$ and $BC$. While it seems like there is enough information, I have tried using similar triangles, etc, but I can't find out the coordinates of the vertices. Can anyone give me some hints? Thank you!

Comment: You have an isosceles triangle with all sides tangent to the circle. The bisector of $\angle BAC$ will go through the center of the circle and will be orthogonal to $BC$.

Comment: What does it mean for $AB$ to have “a positive $y$-coordinate?”

Comment: @amd the line AB touches the y-coordinate at positive mark...i.e. when x=0 then y>0

Comment: @amd Yes I am aware of that. I have found out the coordinates at which $AB$ intersects with the circle. But I am missing the steps to find out the slope of $AC$

Comment: I think there is not enough information

Comment: I agree with @mercio. There’s not enough information for a unique solution. The best you can do, I think, is to have $A$ or $B$ depend on a parameter and give the equations of the other two lines in terms of this parameter. BTW, you could also find the equation for $AB$ by noting that the slope of the tangent to a point $(x,y)$ on the circle is $-x/y$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I will suggest to take $\alpha$ as parameter to write the equation. and you need to take care of the range of  $\alpha$ .

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it looks much clearer with the graph.

Answer (score 1):

I found it fairly straightforward to describe these lines with vector equations.

The line $AB$ is given as having a slope of $\sqrt3$, so it can immediately be parametrized as $\vec P_{AB}=\vec A+t\,(1,\sqrt3)$.

The line $AC$ is the reflection of this line in the line $AO$. A parametrization for this line can be found by reflecting the above parametrization of $AB$. Doing so yields $$\vec P_{AC}=\vec A+t\,\left[2{\vec A\cdot(1,\sqrt3)\over\vec A\cdot\vec A}\vec A-(1,\sqrt3)\right].$$

Finally, since the triangle is isosceles, the line $BC$ is perpendicular to $AO$ and tangent to the circle at the intersection of $AO$ with the circle. This suggests the equation $$\vec P_{BC}\cdot\vec A = \left(-5\frac{\vec A}{\|\vec A\|}\right)\cdot\vec A = -5\|\vec A\|.$$

There’s not enough information to determine a unique value for $A$. It must be farther from the $y$-axis than the point at which $AB$ intersects the circle, $\left(-\frac52\sqrt3,\frac52\right)$, because there’s only one tangent to the circle there and moving any closer takes $B$ out of the first quadrant. On the other hand, when $B$ is on the $y$-axis, the triangle is equilateral, putting $A$ at $(-5\sqrt3,-5)$, so $A$ must be closer to the $y$-axis than this. Combining these constraints gives $$A=\frac52[(-\sqrt3,1)-s\,(\sqrt3,3)]$$ for $0<s<1$. I’ll leave it to you to grind through the algebra and convert these equations into the required forms.

chenbai’s suggestion of using an angle as the parameter seems like a less messy way to go, though. We still derive the equations for $AC$ and $BC$ in the same way. With a slope of $\sqrt3$, $AB$ makes an angle of $\frac\pi3$ with the positive $x$-axis. $AC$ is the reflection of $AB$ with respect to $AO$, so we just need to find the angle of this line, which results in the equation $${y-y_A\over x-x_A}=\tan\left(2\alpha - \frac\pi3\right)$$ for $AC$. We need to express the coordinates of $A$ as a function of $\alpha$, but that’s just a matter of writing the equation for $AB$ in polar form. The bounds for $\alpha$ can be found by making the same considerations as in the vector-based solution above.

Similarly, $BC$ is orthogonal to $AO$, so its equation will be $${y+5\sin\alpha\over x+5\cos\alpha}=\tan\left(\alpha+\frac\pi2\right).$$ The plusses on the left side are because we want the opposite side of the circle from $A$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have worked out how to do it now. Your answer is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

$AB=AC$ suggests to me that line $BC$ is a vertical line and point $A$ is on the negative x-axis. See the picture.

> $A$ has to be on the line perpendicular to segmanet $OP$ at $P$. Put $A$ in the second quadrant and $AB \lt AC$ Put $A$ in the third quadrant and $AB \gt AC$.

Let $P$ be the point where line $AB$ intersects the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 25$. If the slope of line $AB$ is $\sqrt 3$. Then the slope of line $OP$ must be $-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}$. So the line $OP$ is the line $y = -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}x$.

You said you just wanted a hint. So I will let you work out the rest.
[image: My solution]

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the formula of incentre. It is given by $$(x,y)=(\dfrac{ax_1+bx_2+cx_3}{a+b+c},\dfrac{ay_1+by_2+cy_3}{a+b+c})$$

Here $a,b,c $ are the lengths of the sides of the triangle. Length a is opposite to the point A. Length b is opposite to the point B. Length c is opposite to the point C.
Here you can easily see $x=y=0$ & $b=c$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried working on it, but I think there are just too many unknowns but with limited information. Other than the formula you provided, I can't find any other relations between the coordinates of the vertices. Do you have some more ideas?

Comment: @Bubububu did you try distance formula? You can also try using parametric form of straight line.

Comment: I don’t really see how this helps. We’re already given that $x=y=0$ and $b=c$ in the problem statement. Perhaps it helps make clear that there’s not enough information given for a unique solution.